# WPF DataGrid How to Display Blank for Double.Nan?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, nan, display

I have a large amount of data that are carried by a DataTable. Most of the data are doubles; however, many of them are NaN as shown below:

[image]

I'd like to change the display of those NaN values to, say blanks. I know there are some type of converters to achieve that but I don't really know the details. I also know that I can dig into every cell in the data table and programmatically convert NaN to string blanks; however, I'm looking for much easier approaches.

DataGrid in WinForms has an event called CellFormatting where you can change the displayed text at will. However, I cannot find the equivalent in WPF.

Any helps are appreciated.

Note that the DataTable is dynamic in the sense that the columns and rows are not fixed. They change based on the data obtained.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF DataGrid 'CellFormatting Equivalent'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649033/wpf-datagrid-cellformatting-equivalent)

Answer (score 3):

You can add this `CellStyle` for your `DataGrid`

```xml
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Content.Text,
                             Mode=OneWay, 
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                             Value="NaN">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

**Warning:** Everything that is "NaN" will be blank in the view.

Comment: This one worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

You could use a custom converter:

```
public class DoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double d = (double)value;
        if (double.IsNaN(d))
            return string.Empty;

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:DoubleConverter x:Key="converter" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Freight" Binding="{Binding Freight, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mean" Binding="{Binding Mean, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: This approach does not work as my data table is dynamic in the sense that the columns are not pre-defined. They are generated from the data source in run-time. That is, the number of columns and the column headers such as "Freight", "Mean" vary every single time.

Comment: So how do you create the columns? You can obviously set the `Converter` property the same way programmatically.

Comment: I create a binding source from the data table, then assign it to the DataGrid's ItemSource. The grid's columns are automatically generated from the data table columns.

Comment: Then you could handle the `AutoGeneratedColumns` event to create a binding with a converter.